# A case when ConfigureAwait(false) causes an error instead of deadlock

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, synchronizationcontext

Suppose I have written a library which relies on `async` methods:

```
namespace MyLibrary1
{
    public class ClassFromMyLibrary1
    {
        public async Task<string> MethodFromMyLibrary1(string key, Func<string, Task<string>> actionToProcessNewValue)
        {
            var remoteValue = await GetValueByKey(key).ConfigureAwait(false);

            //do some transformations of the value
            var newValue = string.Format("Remote-{0}", remoteValue);

            var processedValue = await actionToProcessNewValue(newValue).ConfigureAwait(false);

            return string.Format("Processed-{0}", processedValue);
        }

        private async Task<string> GetValueByKey(string key)
        {
            //simulate time-consuming operation
            await Task.Delay(500).ConfigureAwait(false);

            return string.Format("ValueFromRemoteLocationBy{0}", key);
        }
    }
}
```

I followed the recommendations of using `ConfigureAwait(false)` (like in [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) post) everywhere in my library. Then I use it in **synchronous** way from my test app and get a failure:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button1_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var c = new ClassFromMyLibrary1();

                var v1 = c.MethodFromMyLibrary1("test1", ActionToProcessNewValue).Result;

                Label2.Content = v1;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError("{0}", ex);
                throw;
            }
        }

        private Task<string> ActionToProcessNewValue(string s)
        {
            Label1.Content = s;
            return Task.FromResult(string.Format("test2{0}", s));
        }
    }
}
```

The failure is:

> WpfApplication1.vshost.exe Error: 0 :
>   System.InvalidOperationException: The calling thread cannot access
>   this object because a different thread owns it.    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.VerifyAccess()    at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp, Object
>   value)    at System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl.set_Content(Object
>   value)    at WpfApplication1.MainWindow.ActionToProcessNewValue(String
>   s) in
>   C:\dev\tests\4\WpfApplication1\WpfApplication1\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line
>   56    at
>   MyLibrary1.ClassFromMyLibrary1.d__0.MoveNext()
>   in
>   C:\dev\tests\4\WpfApplication1\WpfApplication1\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line
>   77
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() 
>   at WpfApplication1.MainWindow.d__1.MoveNext() in
>   C:\dev\tests\4\WpfApplication1\WpfApplication1\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line
>   39 Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in
>   WpfApplication1.exe

Obviously the error happens because the awaiters in my library discard current WPF context.

From the other hand, after removing the `ConfigureAwait(false)` everywhere in the library I obviously get a deadlock instead.

[There is more detailed example of code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/I4VBJs) which explains some constraints that I have to deal with.

So how can I address this issue? What is the best approach here? Do I still need to follow the best practice regarding `ConfigureAwait`?

PS, In real scenario I have many classes and methods therefore tons of such async calls in my library. It's nearly impossible to find out if some particular async call requires context or not (see comments to @Alisson response) to fix it. I don't care about performance though, at least at this point. I'm looking for some general approach to address this issue.

Comment: You don't need to remove `ConfigureAwait(false)` from everywhere, the only place you need to remove it is `await GetValueByKey(key).ConfigureAwait(false);` and it will work. See [Allision's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39106835/80274) for a full explanation why.

Comment: Your requirements are provably impossible to meet.  You want your UI thread to sit there doing nothing, prohibiting it from doing anything until your operation is done, while also having that same operation required to execute some code on the UI thread before it can complete.  Your requirements *mandate* a deadlock.  One of those two requirements will need to go away for the problem to be solvable.

Comment: You are right. I've simplified the client code to demonstrate the _synchronous_ call. In real code I cannot change a way of how the library method is called because it is called from _synchronous_ method which is called by other _synchronous_ method and so on. Eventually this chain comes from GUI event handler.

Comment: The only thing I can do is to `Task.Run(async () => c.MethodFromMyLibrary1)` and don't wait for completion. But this causes other serious issues like error handling and returning result. Hmm, this gets really complicated.

Comment: To better understand my requirements take a look at this detailed code example https://dotnetfiddle.net/I4VBJs

Comment: @Servy, I've posted a new question regarding this second issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39209885/sync-to-async-dispatch-how-can-i-avoid-deadlock

Comment: @neleus Posting the question a second time doesn't change my comment.  You're requirements are provably impossible to meet. You need to change your requirements, not repeat them.

Comment: I hope there is a solution, even for such requirements. Let's see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally a library will document if a callback will be guaranteed to be on the same thread that called it, if it is not documented the safest option will be to assume it does not. Your code example (and the 3rd party you are working with from what I can tell from your comments) fall under the category of "Not guaranteed". In that situation you just need to check if you need to do a `Invoke` from inside the callback method and do it, you can call `Dispatcher.CheckAccess()` and it will return `false` if you need to invoke before using the control.

```
private async Task<string> ActionToProcessNewValue(string s)
{
    //I like to put the work in a delegate so you don't need to type 
    // the same code for both if checks
    Action work = () => Label1.Content = s;
    if(Label1.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    {
        work();
    }
    else
    {
        var operation = Label1.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(work, DispatcherPriority.Send);

        //We likely don't need .ConfigureAwait(false) because we just proved
        // we are not on the UI thread in the if check.
        await operation.Task.ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    return string.Format("test2{0}", s);
}
```

Here is a alternate version with a syncronous callback instead of a async one.

```
private string ActionToProcessNewValue(string s)
{
    Action work = () => Label1.Content = s;
    if(Label1.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    {
        work();
    }
    else
    {
        Label1.Dispatcher.Invoke(work, DispatcherPriority.Send);
    }

    return string.Format("test2{0}", s);
}
```

Here is another version if you wanted to get the value from `Label1.Content` instead of assigning it, this also does not need to use async/await inside the callback.

```
private Task<string> ActionToProcessNewValue(string s)
{
    Func<string> work = () => Label1.Content.ToString();
    if(Label1.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    {
        return Task.FromResult(work());
    }
    else
    {
        return Label1.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(work, DispatcherPriority.Send).Task;
    }
}
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** all of these methods will cause your program to deadlock if you don't get rid of the `.Result` in the button click handler, the `Dispatcher.Invoke` or the `Dispatcher.InvokeAsync` in the callback will never start while it is waiting for `.Result` to return and `.Result` will never return while it is waiting for the callback to return. You must change the click handler to be `async void` and do a `await` instead of the `.Result`.

Comment: So the solution is to change client code in order to make updates in right context. I was assuming this. What is not clear, do I need to remove all `ConfigureAwait(false)` from my library?

Comment: No, keep them in but document in the library that the callbacks may or may-not be on the calling thread when performed. That warns users of the library that they should neither do long running work in the call back nor make assumptions that it is safe to access the UI without checking.

Comment: Once your library does not guarantee it anymore, I guess it's not safe to update a Label in your callback like you're doing, but it is safe to update it after the call you made in your button click event handler (since you just remove the `ConfigureAwait` there).

Comment: @neleus another option is save the value of `SynchronizationContext.Current` as the first line of `MethodFromMyLibrary1` then use [`SynchronizationContext.Send`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.send(v=vs.110).aspx) to do the callback if the context is not null and capture the result, you then continue on with your code once the send completes.

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain, capturing `SynchronizationContext` in the library code is not a good idea. Ideally library developer should not care about synchronization context. I like your suggestion to post the action to UI context from the client code.

Comment: @neleus the .NET framework does it in a lot of places, the first one that comes to mind is when you create a `BackgroundWorker`, it captures the `SynchronizationContext` [when you call `RunWorkerAsync()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/componentmodel/BackgroundWorker.cs,191) using [`AsyncOperationManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.asyncoperationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx)   then it uses that sync context when it raises the events (event's are just a type of callback really) `ProgressChanged` and `RunWorkerCompleted`.

Comment: @neleus Library developers will usually do it if the library is specific for working with UI's, but however I agree, most libraries should not and should rely on the client to do the invoking or using something like a [`IProgress<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138298(v=vs.110).aspx) if you are wanting to report progress of a operation (The implmentation [`Progress<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692(v=vs.110).aspx) included with .NET will capture the context and invoke for you).

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, I've posted a new question on SO about the `.Result` deadlock http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39209885/sync-to-async-dispatch-how-can-i-avoid-deadlock

Answer (score 4):

Actually, you're receiving a callback in your `ClassFromMyLibrary1` and you can't assume what it'll do (like updating a Label). You don't need `ConfigureAwait(false)` in your class library, as the same link you provided gives us an explanation like this:

> As asynchronous GUI applications grow larger, you might find many
>   small parts of async methods all using the GUI thread as their
>   context. This can cause sluggishness as responsiveness suffers from
>   "thousands of paper cuts".
>
> To mitigate this, await the result of ConfigureAwait whenever you can.
>
> By using ConfigureAwait, you enable a small amount of parallelism:
>   Some asynchronous code can run in parallel with the GUI thread instead
>   of constantly badgering it with bits of work to do.

Now take a read here:

> You should not use ConfigureAwait when you have code after the await
>   in the method that needs the context. For GUI apps, this includes any
>   code that manipulates GUI elements, writes data-bound properties or
>   depends on a GUI-specific type such as Dispatcher/CoreDispatcher.

You're doing exactly the opposite. You're trying to update GUI in two points, one in your callback method, and another here:

```
var c = new ClassFromMyLibrary1();

var v1 = c.MethodFromMyLibrary1("test1", ActionToProcessNewValue).Result;

Label2.Content = v1; // updating GUI...
```

That's why removing `ConfigureAwait(false)` solves your problem. Also, you can make your button click handler async and await your `ClassFromMyLibrary1` method call.

Comment: You may want to mention you don't need to remove `.ConfigureAwait(false)`  everywhere to solve the problem, the only place you need to remove it is `await GetValueByKey(key).ConfigureAwait(false);` and it will work because you only need the context up to the point where you call `await actionToProcessNewValue(newValue).ConfigureAwait(false);`, the `.ConfigureAwait(false)` can be kept there and all other places.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain if that class library method calls another, which calls another and so on, they by themselves don't need to capture the context. But what if at some point inside that class library, one of the methods executes a callback function, which tries to update a `Label`, like he is doing? I know the GUI manipulation after the first call without `ConfigureAwait` in the button event handler works, but that callback I don't know for sure. Would it still work? You could improve my answer if you wish, I'd be glad.

Comment: Right, the root of the problem comes from the fact that the library developer doesn't know if some async call needs the context or not. Both calls `await GetValueByKey(key)` and `await actionToProcessNewValue(newValue)` might or might not need the context.

Comment: If I have many async calls in the one method, where each _method calls another, which calls another and so on_ then one of such code paths might lead to a callback to GUI context. Often it's impossible to consider all possible code paths to make a decision regarding `ConfigureAwait(false)`

Comment: @neleus the library developer could use `ConfigureAwait` as soon as it didn't received a callback, because they are sure they don't need the context. Since in this case they can't be sure, it's safer not to use `ConfigureAwait`, I think the performance impact should be little here. If it impacts a lot because you're calling the callback thousands of time or due to low hardware, then it's up to you deciding when to update the `Label`.

Comment: What the library doesn't use any callbacks but interfaces. The interface implementation can update the label. This will cause the same problem but this time without callbacks. I'll provide the code soon.

Comment: @neleus you could inject an interface in the constructor with DI, but you'd have the same problem when you tried to use that interface method. I suggest you remove the `ConfigureAwait` for now, and do some performance test.

Comment: What if the library doesn't use any callbacks but interfaces. The interface implementation can update the label. This will cause the same problem but this time without callbacks. See updated code https://dotnetfiddle.net/A40Zcd

Comment: Right, I can remove it and this way fix _this particular example_. But my question is more general because in real scenario I have many classes and methods therefore a tons of such async calls. It's nearly impossible to fix them all. I don't care about performance though, at least at this point.

Comment: By fix them all, you mean removing the `ConfigureAwait` everywhere? Actually you asked about error instead of deadlock when using `ConfigureAwait`, so I tried to explain what causes this and how to solve. I think if want a solution to use `ConfigureAwait` and also might update GUI in the middle of the calls, then this is more like a design thing. What do you want? You should remove the `ConfigureAwait` at least in all places where you execute that callback method, which needs the context, whether its a `Func<>` or an interface injected in constructor. Do this helps you?

Comment: @Alisson thanks for the suggestions, they helped to identify the root problem. And for now I don't see any other way than redesigning the client code. Let's see what others think.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you should redesign your library API to not mix a callback-based API with a Task-based API.  At least in your example code there's no compelling case to be made to do that and you've nailed one reason not do do that - it is hard to control the context in which your callback runs.

I'd change your library API to be like so:

```
namespace MyLibrary1
{
    public class ClassFromMyLibrary1
    {
        public async Task<string> MethodFromMyLibrary1(string key)
        {
            var remoteValue = await GetValueByKey(key).ConfigureAwait(false);
            return remoteValue;
        }

        public string TransformProcessedValue(string processedValue)
        {
            return string.Format("Processed-{0}", processedValue);
        }

        private async Task<string> GetValueByKey(string key)
        {
            //simulate time-consuming operation
            await Task.Delay(500).ConfigureAwait(false);

            return string.Format("ValueFromRemoteLocationBy{0}", key);
        }
    }
}
```

And call it like so:

```
   private async void Button1_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var c = new ClassFromMyLibrary1();

            var v1 = await c.MethodFromMyLibrary1("test1");
            var v2 = await ActionToProcessNewValue(v1);
            var v3 = c.TransformProcessedValue(v2);

            Label2.Content = v3;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError("{0}", ex);
            throw;
        }
    }

    private Task<string> ActionToProcessNewValue(string s)
    {
        Label1.Content = s;
        return Task.FromResult(string.Format("test2{0}", s));
    }
```

Comment: What if `ActionToProcessNewValue` is declared inside some interface and `ClassFromMyLibrary1` accepts it in constructor? Anyway the code can be much more complicated and the callback might lead to long chain of injected classes (for example using DI). That's why it may not be possible to redesign it.

Comment: BTW, I've corrected the method `Button1_OnClick` and made it synchronous because this is a requirement.