# Sync to async dispatch: how can I avoid deadlock?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, async-await, deadlock

I'm trying to create a class that has synchronous methods and calls some other library methods which are asynchronous. For that reason I use `Task.Result` to wait for the async operation to finish. My methods are called by WPF app in synchronous way. This leads to a deadlock. I know that the best way is to make all my methods asynchronous but my situation requires them to be synchronous. From the other hand they use other library which is asynchronous.

My question is: How can I avoid the deadlock in such situation?

Steps to reproduce:

1. User hits a button in the app (method `Button1_OnClick`)
2. This method creates an instance of `IPlugin` and then calls its method `RequestSomething()`
3. This method then calls async library this way: `asyncTarget.MethodFromAsyncLibrary("HelloFromPlugin").Result`
4. The library calls back its method `NotifyNewValueProgressAsync()`
5. `NotifyNewValueProgressAsync()` delegates the call back to the WPF application
6. Since the UI context is blocked by this line `asyncTarget.MethodFromAsyncLibrary("HelloFromPlugin").Result` the callback in step 5 leads to a deadlock.

See code example below and related comments:

```
public class SyncAdapterPlugin : IPlugin, IProgressAsyncHandler
{
    //Constructor and fields are omitted here

    //This method is called from UI context by WPF application and it delegates synchronous call to asynchronous method
    string IPlugin.RequestSomething()
    {
        //In order to be able to run the callback I need to capture current UI context
        _context = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

        var asyncTarget = new ClassFromMyLibrary1(this);
        var resultFromAsyncLibrary = asyncTarget.MethodFromAsyncLibrary("HelloFromPlugin").Result; //Deadlock here!
        return resultFromAsyncLibrary;
    }

    //This method does opposite, it delegates asynchronous callback to synchronous
    async Task<bool> IProgressAsyncHandler.NotifyNewValueProgressAsync(string message)
    {
        //NotifyNewValueProgress method is implemented by WPF application and will update UI elements.
        //That's why it's needed to run the callback on captured UI context.
        Func<bool> work = () => _syncProgressHandler.NotifyNewValueProgress(message);
        if (_context != null)
        {
            return await
                Task.Factory.StartNew(work, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, _context)
                .ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        return work();
    }
}
```

Complete code example is here https://dotnetfiddle.net/i48sRc.

FYI, Some background on this issue you can also find in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39105998/a-case-when-configureawaitfalse-causes-an-error-instead-of-deadlock).

Comment: I feel there's not enough code here to deduce anything useful. Could you please describe the steps required to reach a deadlock?

Comment: Did you check the full example here https://dotnetfiddle.net/i48sRc  ?

Comment: There are no steps there either, which would tells us how to reach deadlock.

Comment: I've added them, see updated post

Comment: Are you sure this won't block current UI thread?

Comment: @Igor Then it simply won't work, as the method is specifically designed to run in the UI thread.  That'll just make it fail.

Comment: I fail to see why you are mixing async/sync code? Its a button, mark the click event handler as async and make the entire call stack use async calls with the async/await pattern to avoid locking or blocking.

Comment: I cannot change the code of app because I have no access, see full example with comments https://dotnetfiddle.net/i48sRc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin framework is fundamentally flawed. In particular, it requires a *synchronous* `RequestSomething` that expects to be able to call `NotifyNewValueProgressAsync` to update the UI. However, it's not possible to display a UI update while the UI thread is running a synchronous method.

This *forces* you to use one of the most dangerous and evil sync-over-async hacks: the [nested message loop hack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238404.aspx) (as briefly described in my article on brownfield async). Since this is a WPF app, you'd use a [nested dispatcher frame](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870(v=vs.110).aspx). The main pain with this hack is that it introduces reentrancy across your entire UI layer, which is the most subtle and difficult kind of concurrency problem.

Comment: Thanks, that article was really helpful! I'd recommend reading it for every library developer at least for those who deal with legacy _sync_ code which are most people today. Can you also give a link to read about the reentracy? My understanding is that it's kind of hidden recursion in nested event loop but not sure.

Answer (score 0):

By definition a synchronous method isn't going to be asynchronous. You will need to wrap the calls to the synchronous methods from the UI in a Task using TAP and await them there while making the method you await from asynchronous.

Comment: That's what `TaskCompletionSource` was made for. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174(v=vs.110).aspx)